# What does inner product actually mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question

What does inner product actually mean? So far most of the cases that I encounter seems to suggest that dot product is the only useful inner product. I mean most of the things that we discuss about defines inner product as dot product. For example, when we talk about norm or length of a vector. If that is the case, why do we need inner product? I don't really get the purpose of defining such thing.

Comment: For instance, you could look at the examples section here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space

Answer (score 10):

Inner product tells you how much of one vector is pointing in the direction of another one. If e is a unit vector then $<f, e>$ is the component of f in the direction of e and the vector component of f in the direction e is $<f, e>e$. The vectors f and e are orthogonal when $<f, e> = 0$, in which case f has zero component in the direction e.
In 2 dimensions and with dot product this is familiar. We can write any vector v as $<v, i>i + <v, j>j$ where i and j are unit vectors in the direction of the x and y axes.

More interestingly, consider the space of real square integrable continuous functions on the interval [0, 1] and inner product $<f, g>=\int_{0}^{1}f(x)g(x)dx$. With respect to this inner product the functions $u_n=sin(2n\pi x)$ and $v_n=cos(2n\pi x)$ are orthonormal for each n, just like the usual basis vectors in n dimensions. A function (vector) in our space can now be written as (modulo some technicalities) 
$$\sum_{0}^{\infty}(<f,u_n>)sin(2n\pi x)+<f,v_n>cos(2n\pi x))$$

the real fourier series for f. That is one use of the inner product - it lets you visualize function spaces geometrically.

Comment: Strictly speaking, your example is not an inner product since it's not positive definite.

Comment: I'm only looking at real valued functions to illustrate the point.

Comment: Inner product requires $<f,g>=0 \implies f=g$. But $\int_0^1 f\,dx=0 \implies f=0$ almost everywhere.

Comment: fair enough, restrict to the continuous functions.

Comment: Six years too late, but inner products do not require that $ \langle f, g  \rangle = 0 \implies f = g $. For instance, take $e_1, e_2 \in \mathbb{R}^2$ with the standard dot product. Positive definiteness is $\langle f, f \rangle =0 \implies f =0$ The above absolutely is an inner product, and the positive definiteness is simply the fact that $\int_0^1 |f|^2 dm = 0 \implies f =0$ a.e., which follows from the fact that $|f|^2 \geq 0$

Comment: @msm Sorry to make a fuss about this. I agree the definition of positive definiteness was incorrect. But isn't it still necessary to have the condition $f$ is continuous for the statement $(\int_0^1 |f|^2 dm = 0 \implies f = 0) $ to be true?

Comment: Kind of. This is why $L^2$ is secretly a space of equivalence classes, rather than functions. Basically, given two functions $f$ and $g$, we call them equivalent if they are equal *almost everywhere* (look up). Then, we take all square integrable functions, and form the corresponding equivalence classes and define the vector space structure on the equivalence classes (the downside to this is you need to take a second to make sure these operations are well defined, but thats not too bad). Now, if you have $\int |f|^2 =0$ then $f=0$ a.e., so the equivalence class of $f$ is that of $0$, as needed

Comment: There's a lot of content in my above comment, so if its confusing I'm sorry. The main point is that there are ways to get around needing $f=0$ at every point. I could get more in to the motivation for doing that, but I've already overcomplicated things.

Answer (score 2):

The inner product is not necessarily the best way to think of it; I would argue that *orthogonality* is the more useful concept. It's nice to know when things are perpendicular, and the inner product provides us with a way of determining that in contexts more general than, say, $\mathbb{R}^N$.

Why is it useful? Well, it's nice to be able to decompose vector spaces (even infinite dimensional ones!) into collections of mutually orthogonal subspaces.

For example, given a subspace $V \subset W$ of some vector space, when do you know that you can write $W = V \oplus V'$ in a nice way? Well, if there is an inner product on $W$ then there is a natural way to do so; just define $V' = V^\perp$. Without that there is not necessarily a natural choice of complement.

Answer (score 1):

Inner product is a generalization for dot product on a space $X$. And with this generalization, we can define the angle between two elements in $X$ and we can talk about perpendicular, projection of one element on the other element's direction, minimum distance and so on.

For example, we can define an inner product on $C[0,1]$ by $<f,g>=\int_{0}^1 f(x)g(x)\, dx$.